# Displaying array in a firestore document onto a recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore Dadabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmX2E.png)

I am having some trouble displaying an array of dates from a document onto a recyclerview. I am stuck on the query part. On previous work, I've done something like this

```
 var absentQuery = db.collection("Users").whereArrayContains("absentDate", "1-1-2021")
```

In that code I pasted it would query all the documents in the collection `Users` and look for an array field. But this time, I only want the array from a specific document. How would I display the array `absentDates` in document `j9gaXg4ywQYxYigirx09DUWuGP82` using a recyclerview?

UPDATE:
So I am still stuck on this problem. So I know the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` requires an `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` as an argument. So I would use `FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder` create the `FirestoreRecyclerOptions`. It seems like I would only be able to create one model class for every `DocumentSnapshot`. So the problem is the `DocumentSnapshot` has the array with the dates and each date would be a model. This is currently what I have for the `FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder`

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<AbsentDateData>() 
.setQuery(query, SnapshotParser<AbsentDateData> { 
val dates = it.get("absentDates") as List<String> 
AbsentDateData(dates) }).build()
```

Comment: Have you got document id directly ?

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking if I know the document ids? Yeah, I have the document ids that I would like to query.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display in the RecyclerView, only those three (1-1-2021, 2-1-2021, 3-1-2021) dates?

Comment: Yup, everything in `absentDates`